# How to use /psfrag with pdf Foto

Tags: compiling, psfrag

I am relatively new in latex and would write my bachelor thesis with it. I would edit photos with /psfrag in latex. The photos I use are saved as pdf files.

My first script is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{graphicx}
        
\geometry{
            papersize={190mm,160mm},
            left=20mm,
            top=20mm,
            }
        
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\psfrag{001}[bc][bc]{Einheit}%
\psfrag{002}[lt][lt]{$-10$}%
\psfrag{003}[lt][lt]{$0$}%
\psfrag{004}[lt][lt]{$10$}%
\psfrag{005}[lt][lt]{$20$}%
\psfrag{006}[lt][lt]{$30$}%
\psfrag{007}[rc][rc]{$-50$}%
\psfrag{008}[rc][rc]{$-40$}%
\psfrag{009}[rc][rc]{$-30$}%
\psfrag{010}[rc][rc]{$-20$}%
\includegraphics{TEST.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I use texstudio with Build commands
txs:///latex | txs:///dvips | txs:///ps2pdf | txs:///view

The error message is
Cannot determine size of graphic in TEST.pdf (no BoundingBox). \includegraphics{TEST.pdf}

How to run the script correctly?
looking for the correct compiling format

I have actually searched for a long time for a solution to my problem but unfortunately found nothing helpful.

Comment: you would need to convert  the pdf to ps first, psfrag reads (e)ps files not pdf.

Comment: also psfrag requires text to be stored as fonts in the eps. If by "Foto" you mean you have photographs or scanned images, psfrag will not work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle how can I do that without losing the accuracy?
With Foto I meant Photo sorry it is a gramen word. Yes, the PDF is vectorized photo with some text.

Comment: so not a photograph (ie with not a camera or scanner). conversion between postscript and pdf is (usually) lossless, they are very similar formats designed by same the company.

Comment: Please take a look at the pdf file and tell me how to convert it

https://www.dropbox.com/s/srqvdpibwys5cks/001_DENSITY_distribution.pdf?dl=0